# Altering values in a key, value pair in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
matrix = 
(724, -421) {'(18, 430)': 0, '(19, 430)': 0, '(19, 429)': 0, '(19, 428)': 0, '(19, 427)': 0, '(18, 426)': 0, '(17, 426)': 0, '(17, 425)': 0, '(17, 424)': 0, '(17, 423)': 0, '(17, 422)': 0, '(17, 421)': 0, '(17, 420)': 0, '(16, 421)': 0, '(14, 420)': 0, '(11, 419)': 0, '(9, 417)': 0, '(7, 416)': 0, '(4, 414)': 0, '(3, 414)': 0, '(2, 412)': 0, '(1, 412)': 0, '(-1, 410)': 0, '(-2, 409)': 0, '(-2, 408)': 0, '(-3, 407)': 0, '(-3, 406)': 0, '(-3, 405)': 0, '(-3, 404)': 0, '(-3, 403)': 0, '(-3, 402)': 0, '(-3, 401)': 0, '(-3, 400)': 0, '(-4, 399)': 0, '(-4, 398)': 0, '(-5, 398)': 0, '(-6, 398)': 0, '(-7, 397)': 0, '(-7, 396)': 0, '(-6, 395)': 0, '(-5, 395)': 0, '(-4, 393)': 0, '(-3, 391)': 0, '(6, 384)': 0, '(12, 378)': 0, '(24, 370)': 0, '(42, 358)': 0, '(107, 304)': 0, '(151, 255)': 0, '(207, 196)': 0, '(259, 121)': 0, '(389, -28)': 0, '(456, -84)': 0, '(515, -134)': 0, '(569, -182)': 0, '(650, -260)': 0, '(688, -294)': 0, '(723, -317)': 0, '(740, -328)': 0, '(762, -342)': 0, '(767, -347)': 0, '(768, -349)': 0, '(769, -352)': 0, '(769, -357)': 0, '(769, -359)': 0, '(768, -361)': 0, '(768, -364)': 0, '(766, -370)': 0, '(765, -371)': 0, '(764, -374)': 0, '(763, -376)': 0, '(761, -378)': 0, '(760, -381)': 0, '(758, -385)': 0, '(752, -394)': 0, '(747, -401)': 0, '(742, -407)': 0, '(735, -413)': 0, '(724, -421)': 0, '(719, -424)': 1, '(718, -425)': 0, '(717, -425)': 0}
(719, -424) {'(18, 430)': 0, '(19, 430)': 0, '(19, 429)': 0, '(19, 428)': 0, '(19, 427)': 0, '(18, 426)': 0, '(17, 426)': 0, '(17, 425)': 0, '(17, 424)': 0, '(17, 423)': 0, '(17, 422)': 0, '(17, 421)': 0, '(17, 420)': 0, '(16, 421)': 0, '(14, 420)': 0, '(11, 419)': 0, '(9, 417)': 0, '(7, 416)': 0, '(4, 414)': 0, '(3, 414)': 0, '(2, 412)': 0, '(1, 412)': 0, '(-1, 410)': 0, '(-2, 409)': 0, '(-2, 408)': 0, '(-3, 407)': 0, '(-3, 406)': 0, '(-3, 405)': 0, '(-3, 404)': 0, '(-3, 403)': 0, '(-3, 402)': 0, '(-3, 401)': 0, '(-3, 400)': 0, '(-4, 399)': 0, '(-4, 398)': 0, '(-5, 398)': 0, '(-6, 398)': 0, '(-7, 397)': 0, '(-7, 396)': 0, '(-6, 395)': 0, '(-5, 395)': 0, '(-4, 393)': 0, '(-3, 391)': 0, '(6, 384)': 0, '(12, 378)': 0, '(24, 370)': 0, '(42, 358)': 0, '(107, 304)': 0, '(151, 255)': 0, '(207, 196)': 0, '(259, 121)': 0, '(389, -28)': 0, '(456, -84)': 0, '(515, -134)': 0, '(569, -182)': 0, '(650, -260)': 0, '(688, -294)': 0, '(723, -317)': 0, '(740, -328)': 0, '(762, -342)': 0, '(767, -347)': 0, '(768, -349)': 0, '(769, -352)': 0, '(769, -357)': 0, '(769, -359)': 0, '(768, -361)': 0, '(768, -364)': 0, '(766, -370)': 0, '(765, -371)': 0, '(764, -374)': 0, '(763, -376)': 0, '(761, -378)': 0, '(760, -381)': 0, '(758, -385)': 0, '(752, -394)': 0, '(747, -401)': 0, '(742, -407)': 0, '(735, -413)': 0, '(724, -421)': 0, '(719, -424)': 0, '(718, -425)': 1, '(717, -425)': 0}
(718, -425) {'(18, 430)': 0, '(19, 430)': 0, '(19, 429)': 0, '(19, 428)': 0, '(19, 427)': 0, '(18, 426)': 0, '(17, 426)': 0, '(17, 425)': 0, '(17, 424)': 0, '(17, 423)': 0, '(17, 422)': 0, '(17, 421)': 0, '(17, 420)': 0, '(16, 421)': 0, '(14, 420)': 0, '(11, 419)': 0, '(9, 417)': 0, '(7, 416)': 0, '(4, 414)': 0, '(3, 414)': 0, '(2, 412)': 0, '(1, 412)': 0, '(-1, 410)': 0, '(-2, 409)': 0, '(-2, 408)': 0, '(-3, 407)': 0, '(-3, 406)': 0, '(-3, 405)': 0, '(-3, 404)': 0, '(-3, 403)': 0, '(-3, 402)': 0, '(-3, 401)': 0, '(-3, 400)': 0, '(-4, 399)': 0, '(-4, 398)': 0, '(-5, 398)': 0, '(-6, 398)': 0, '(-7, 397)': 0, '(-7, 396)': 0, '(-6, 395)': 0, '(-5, 395)': 0, '(-4, 393)': 0, '(-3, 391)': 0, '(6, 384)': 0, '(12, 378)': 0, '(24, 370)': 0, '(42, 358)': 0, '(107, 304)': 0, '(151, 255)': 0, '(207, 196)': 0, '(259, 121)': 0, '(389, -28)': 0, '(456, -84)': 0, '(515, -134)': 0, '(569, -182)': 0, '(650, -260)': 0, '(688, -294)': 0, '(723, -317)': 0, '(740, -328)': 0, '(762, -342)': 0, '(767, -347)': 0, '(768, -349)': 0, '(769, -352)': 0, '(769, -357)': 0, '(769, -359)': 0, '(768, -361)': 0, '(768, -364)': 0, '(766, -370)': 0, '(765, -371)': 0, '(764, -374)': 0, '(763, -376)': 0, '(761, -378)': 0, '(760, -381)': 0, '(758, -385)': 0, '(752, -394)': 0, '(747, -401)': 0, '(742, -407)': 0, '(735, -413)': 0, '(724, -421)': 0, '(719, -424)': 0, '(718, -425)': 0, '(717, -425)': 1}
(717, -425) {'(18, 430)': 0, '(19, 430)': 0, '(19, 429)': 0, '(19, 428)': 0, '(19, 427)': 0, '(18, 426)': 0, '(17, 426)': 0, '(17, 425)': 0, '(17, 424)': 0, '(17, 423)': 0, '(17, 422)': 0, '(17, 421)': 0, '(17, 420)': 0, '(16, 421)': 0, '(14, 420)': 0, '(11, 419)': 0, '(9, 417)': 0, '(7, 416)': 0, '(4, 414)': 0, '(3, 414)': 0, '(2, 412)': 0, '(1, 412)': 0, '(-1, 410)': 0, '(-2, 409)': 0, '(-2, 408)': 0, '(-3, 407)': 0, '(-3, 406)': 0, '(-3, 405)': 0, '(-3, 404)': 0, '(-3, 403)': 0, '(-3, 402)': 0, '(-3, 401)': 0, '(-3, 400)': 0, '(-4, 399)': 0, '(-4, 398)': 0, '(-5, 398)': 0, '(-6, 398)': 0, '(-7, 397)': 0, '(-7, 396)': 0, '(-6, 395)': 0, '(-5, 395)': 0, '(-4, 393)': 0, '(-3, 391)': 0, '(6, 384)': 0, '(12, 378)': 0, '(24, 370)': 0, '(42, 358)': 0, '(107, 304)': 0, '(151, 255)': 0, '(207, 196)': 0, '(259, 121)': 0, '(389, -28)': 0, '(456, -84)': 0, '(515, -134)': 0, '(569, -182)': 0, '(650, -260)': 0, '(688, -294)': 0, '(723, -317)': 0, '(740, -328)': 0, '(762, -342)': 0, '(767, -347)': 0, '(768, -349)': 0, '(769, -352)': 0, '(769, -357)': 0, '(769, -359)': 0, '(768, -361)': 0, '(768, -364)': 0, '(766, -370)': 0, '(765, -371)': 0, '(764, -374)': 0, '(763, -376)': 0, '(761, -378)': 0, '(760, -381)': 0, '(758, -385)': 0, '(752, -394)': 0, '(747, -401)': 0, '(742, -407)': 0, '(735, -413)': 0, '(724, -421)': 0, '(719, -424)': 0, '(718, -425)': 0, '(717, -425)': 3}....
```

In Python, if we have key, value pairs in a dictionary that look like
the dictionary matrix above:

where the keys are: `(724, -421), (719, -424), (718,-425), (717, -425)....`

and the values are the items in the braces `{}` how can we change the values
so that we remove the parenthesis and colon from each of the values and only keep
the numbers after the colon. I think we would have to use the replace function but I am not sure.

Comment: Please post some valid python. I have no idea what object `matrix` is.

Comment: Please add an example of what you expect to get and clarify what your code is and does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
matrix = {
    (724, -421): {'(18, 430)': 0, '(19, 430)': 0, '(19, 429)': 0},
    (719, -424): {'(18, 430)': 0, '(19, 430)': 0, '(19, 429)': 0},
    (717, -425): {'(18, 430)': 0, '(19, 430)': 0, '(19, 429)': 0}
}

for key in matrix.keys():
    matrix[key] = list(matrix[key].values())

print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
{(724, -421): [0, 0, 0], 
 (719, -424): [0, 0, 0],
 (717, -425): [0, 0, 0]}
```